# difference between OLS and f_oneway (Anova)

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, anova, p-value

> I did **anova test** b/w 'density' : continuous,  'quality':catagorical,
>   but got different F-statics and p-value.
>
> now I am confused which one should i use to reject or support null
>   hypothesis.

```
 import  statsmodels.formula.api as smf
 import patsy

formula = 'density ~ C(quality)'
y,x = patsy.dmatrices(formula, wine_train, return_type='dataframe')
smf.OLS(y,x).fit().summary()
```

> F-statistic:  9.093 
>   Prob (F-statistic):   1.73e-08

[ols result: image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHdUa.jpg)

But anova test{f_oneway} is giving differnt F and p-value.

```
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups

stats.f_oneway(wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[3],
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[4],
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[5],
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[6],
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[7],
wine_train[['density','quality']].groupby('quality').groups[8])

**F_onewayResult(statistic=3.2489023202821761, pvalue=0.0064318288153747899)**
```

> may you give me idea that OLS and f_oneway are different or sthing.